# qt: is my window overlapped by other?

Tags: winapi, qt

I know some solution in WINAPI with enum all visible window to check intersect with my window...

But I need crossplatform solution for Qt (3 or 4 - no metter), maybe someone can help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you specify more clearly what your platform requirements are. Do you want to do this for all platforms where Qt runs?

Answer (score 0):

To simply check if your window is active/has the keyboard focus you can check whether the [Qt::WindowState](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#WindowState-enum) is Qt::WindowActive.

---

To check your window for overlappings/intersections with other windows (I think that was your question) I can only think of using a little work-around.

The QWidget class has a function [QWidget::visibleRegion()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#visibleRegion) which returns a QRegion. Basically this region is the space in which paint-events can occur, that means that this is the space not covered by anything else. You can check whether the size of this region roughly matches the size of your window to see if there is any space covered by something else.

I didn't test this, so I can't tell you if it works for all platforms you need it to work on.

**Edit:** According to your comment:
This is what I found in the qt 4.6 reference about `visibleRegion()`:

> Returns the unobscured region where
>   paint events can occur. For visible
>   widgets, this is an approximation of
>   the area not covered by other widgets.

So if the size of this unobscured region is approximately the size of your window, then your window isn't covered by anything.

Comment: "simply check Qt::WindowActive" doesn't work because click on trayicon change active state to non-active, and isWindowActive() return always false

Comment: Jep, I forgot. Maybe my second proposal is more suitable for your requirement.

Comment: visibleRegion() always (why?) return full area of window and return non-valid values only is window is hidden, so... any ideas?